# XSLT - make everything below the root element a children of a new element

Tags: xml, xslt

Any ideas on how this can be achieved please.
So regardless of the xml structure, I want to create a new element below the root, and make everything below the root in the source xml a child of this new element.

Regards

Steve

Comment: This is trivial.

Comment: However, the requirement as expressed is ambiguous. In the XSLT 1.0 data model, the "root" is the document node. But the question title refers to the "root element" which typically refers to the outermost element, a child of the XDM root. It's also unclear whether attributes of the "root element" are "below" it.

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree that the question is ambiguous (which is why I voted to close it). However, once clarified, the answer is trivial - no matter which of the interpretations is correct. I did not think it deserved an answer, let alone 3 different ones.

Answer (score 2):

It does depend on exactly what you mean, and how you want to handle namespaces and attributes, but I suspect it's something like

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <new-element>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </new-element>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with stylesheet parameters where you indicate if you want to keep the root element's attributes in the root element.  Also, you pass in the name of the new child element.  Probably some extra work required for adding a namespaced child element.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:param name="keepRootAttributes" select="false()" />
  <xsl:param name="newElementName"     select="'new_child'" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="$keepRootAttributes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:element name="{$newElementName}">
        <xsl:if test="not($keepRootAttributes)" >
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```